# AngularJS curly braces aren't resolving, but ng-bind works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django

I am working on a Django app and I am using AngularJS for my front end. I have a simple code

```html
<div class="vert-carousel" ng-controller="PrizeController">
    <div class="gallery-cell" ng-repeat="p in getPrizes()">
        <div class="car-item">
            <img ng-src="{{ p.thumbnail }}" alt="Can't load the image">
            <p><div  ng-bind="p.thumbnail"> </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller code is as below:

```js
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('mainApp')
    .controller('PrizeController', PrizeController);

PrizeController.$inject = ['$scope', 'CompetitionService', 'PrizeService'];

function PrizeController($scope, CompetitionService, PrizeService) {
    $scope.competition = CompetitionService.getCompetition();
    $scope.prizes = [];
    $scope.showPrice = true;
    $scope.detailLink = "/#!/prize/";

    $scope.getPrizes = function () {
       console.log ("GetPrizes");
        console.log($scope.prizes);
        return $scope.prizes; //PrizeService.getCurrentWeekList();
    };

    function init() {
        PrizeService.getCurrentWeekList().then(function(data) {
            console.log ("Init called");
            console.log(data);
            $scope.prizes = data;
        })
    }

    init();
}
})();
```

What's happening is that, in the front end, the {{p.thumbnail}} in the img ng-src tag isn't resolving. In fact, if I use the curly braces anywhere in the code, I am unable to resolve it. But, the same values are displaying with ng-bind instead. In my code, I am trying to resolve p.thumbnail with both the {{}} and ng-bind, and the latter works. My output looks like this:

[Link to the output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuyHo.png)

Please help me understand why the {{}} aren't working.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting `p.thumbnail`?

Comment: thumbnail is a part of the object returned to $scope.prizes. It is populated from the backend.

Comment: Can you share the markup after it is rendered? What is the value of the ng-src attribute? Is there a src attribute set?

Comment: The ng-src is blank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is a template that's rendered by Django first, than the Django Template engine will replace all `{{ something }}` with whatever it can resolve that to.

This means that by the time the code gets to the browser and AngularJS loads it up, there aren't any curly braces left in the code to resolve, just (probably) blanks.

In order to go around this, AngularJS allows you to change what the characters for template markup are, via an `interpolationProvider`. Here's the [docs link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider). I usually use `[[ ]]`.

Here's the example from the link above and how to integrate it in your app:

```
var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('//');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('//');
});


customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
    this.label = "This binding is brought you by // interpolation symbols.";
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. It is a Django template. I'll try your recommendation and revert. Cheers.

Comment: If your angular app is compact you could also use the [verbatim block](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) which tells the template renderer not to replace the variables within the block.